# Not making a wedding on the first 3 days of a month

Tags: minhag, calendar, wedding

I've heard there is a custom (practiced in various kehillas, I heard Belz is one of them) to not make a wedding on the first 3 days of a month (meaning alef, beis, or gimmel of a particular month.) Does anyone know where this custom comes from? Which kehillas have this custom? Is it mentioned in poskim? What are the reasons for it (if any?)

Comment: Perhaps [YD 179:2](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x5167)?

Comment: @Yehoshua: Here is the corrected link. http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46545&st=&pgnum=295

Comment: possibly related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/55482/said-kiddush-levana-prior-to-three-days-after-molad-does-he-say-it-again/55496#comment218592_55496