# Can one say Kiddush Levana on Rosh Hodesh or the 2nd day of the month if he won't be able to otherwise?

Tags: halacha, kiddush-levanah

*Kiddush Levana* can be recited as early as the [3rd day of the Hebrew month](http://opensiddur.org/set-prayers/moon-cycle/new-moon/kiddush-levanah-sanctification-of-the-moon-rabbi-david-seidenberg-neohasid-org/).

Two scenarios (may have same or different answers):

A. Suppose a person will be hospitalized beginning the 3rd of the month (or some other reason that would make him physically unable to recite it.)

B. A person lives in an area where overcast skies are almost a guarantee. E.eg. fog is an almost nightly occurrence in San Francisco (and IIRC, certain parts of Israel), esp. during the summer. Or, the forecast predicts rain / clouds for the next 2 weeks (perhaps, rare, but, it has happened in NY area numerous times. Meteorologists call it a "stationary front".)

Can a person recite *Kiddush Levana* early in either of these (or similar) situations?

Comment: probably yes http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/55496/759 Your case sounds highly unlikely, I might add.

Comment: The 72 hour point after the molad can be earlier than the third day of the month. For example, the 72 hour point in San Francisco for Tamuz was 5:34 PM PDT Friday (which was the second of Tamuz before Shkiah). You should express your question in that way. You would also need to determine how long the moon is visible and if it is sufficiently separated from the sun to be seen after the sun has set.

Comment: You're assuming weather forecasts are recognized by halacha. I believe we generally assume that, e.g., one is chayyiv to sleep in the sukkah even if the forecast predicts rain.

Comment: @Loewian No such assumption. I don't even know what it means for weather forecasts to be "recognized" or not, or how your case with Sukkah shows that (by Sukkah we look at the weather now and ignore what will happen later). Being worried about clouds in the winter is a longstanding Jewish tradition.

Comment: http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=51473&st=&pgnum=642&hilite=

Comment: @DoubleAA Good find! He explicitly addresses someone who may become ill who can do it as early as 3 days after the molad.